# Best datastructure to use

Tags: java, algorithms, performance, data-structures

I am using Amazon's dynamodb nosql database and as a result I need to think of some ways to do certain operations to fit into their limits (e.g 4k item limit, can't combine small items into the same read operation, etc).

One such issue is I will have a database attribute which will contain a long string (the string will look something like this: [username1],[username2],[username200]). From this string I will need to be able to search for a user, add a user, and delete a user. If a user is added or deleted I will need to create a string again so it can be uploaded back into the database.

I will be writing this in Java and so my idea is to parse the string into some data structure and then interact with this data structure to be able to find and modify users. First idea which came to mind is to use a an arraylist and use Java's collection 'contains' method to see if a username exists, but this will work in O(n) time.

I was looking to see if I kept the items ordered (although from a requirement standpoint I do not need the users sorted) if this would help, but the it seems contains is always O(n) time.

I was looking at hashsets, but the cpu overhead to calculate hashes I think will be to costly as this scenario of manipulating the string will happen quite often. What would be a good data structure to use then to be able to:

1. See if a user exists,
2. Add a user to structure which then needs to appended to the string
3. Delete a user from the structure which then needs to not be added to the string.

I will be doing more retrievals than insert/updates so I have been reading an avl trees look to be a possible option then as my data structure is small (200 elements) and most operations will work in O(log(n))?Is there a better structure or any pro/cons to using avl trees?

Comment: Why do you think calculating hashes of strings will be too costly?

Comment: @Snowman I am running this on a low end machine in the Amazon cloud. The system is a dual-core system with 3GB of ram. Since hashsets need additional CPU overhead my thinking is it would be best if I could avoid cpu overhead and still have quite good performance. As well, since I need to then recreate the String I am not sure how much overhead is involved with iterating over a hashset? I am by no means opposed to using hashes if the permanence is good. My thinking also is  if something runs O(log(200)) then it is almost as good as O(1) without the cpu overhead.

Comment: I recommend looking at the implementation of `String.hashCode()`. It caches the value. Since `String` is immutable, odds are that a particular string will only ever need its hash calculated... once. Plus, it is a simple calculation optimized for speed. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/299304 - its answers go into detail about _why_ that hashcode implementation is fast.

Comment: There is a reason why Java's `HashMap` is used as a code equivalent of a SQL table accessed via PK: given what I already stated, using `String` as its key is _very_ efficient and that is a very common key type.

Comment: When Java's String class was created, an average machine ran at 75 Mhz and had 8 MB of RAM.  Those machines had no troubles generating hashcodes.  The whole point of HashSets is that they are fast.

Comment: Looks like hashSets don't have the lardge overhead I thought they did!

Comment: When you wrote "but the cpu overhead to calculate hashes I think will be too costly", did you do any measurements? If not, better delete your question, or at least remove the false assumptions.

Comment: Also, since you clearly have a one-to-many relationship between rows of this table and usernames, why not put all the names in a separate table so you don't have to fiddle with string searching/concatenation at all? Does that break the 4k item limit? (if performance is a legitimate issue, I'd look at this first)

Comment: @lxrec With Dynamodb you have X number of read operation/second. If I use a 'Contacts' table and need to get 200 contacts for a user that is 200 read operations taken up by a single request, so with the number of users we have this adds up and becomes very expensive.